# Recover Reference to Browser Window Once Lost?

Tags: javascript

My software allows users to Chat in a new browser window:

```
chatWindow = window.open(url, "chatWindow");
```

I can store a reference to this window in a collection and use it as needed. The main thing I do with this reference is checking to prevent more than one chat window from being opened at a time.

My question is that once the chatWindow is open, the user can navigate the original browser window to, say, www.google.com. In this case, the chatWindow is still open and chatting fine. My issue is that the user can then return to my application and open another chatwindow, since I have lost my original reference to it. Is there a way to regain this reference once it has been lost? Perhaps referencing the Window by name?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use postMessage to communicate between tabs

2) You can set cookies

3) Local Storage etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something you could solve with localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Comment: How would you handle this, like so? chatWindow = window.open(url, "chatWindow"); localStorage.setItem('chatWindow', chatWindow); chatWindow.onbeforeunload = function() { localStorage.removeItem('chatWindow'); };

Comment: After trying localStorage, it does not appear to work in this situation. The issue is that I need to remove the item when the window is closed. See the code above, the onbeforeunload handler only fires if I am currently on the page that opened the Window. If I navigate away, that handler is lost and the item is never removed.